# Laravel validate get request with numbers

Tags: php, laravel

How I can validate get request with only numbers [20, 50, 100]? 
My Code:

```
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'limit' => 'sometimes|integer|min:20|max:100',
    ]);
```

How I can do this with my rules?

Comment: use custom validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the "in" rule which tests whether the value is in the list you give :

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'limit' => 'sometimes|integer|in:20,50,100',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'limit' => 'sometimes|integer|regex:/^(50|20|100)$/'
]);
```

Comment: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found